# JS pop-up for different items on page

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a pop-up for each item in my app to select quantity.

So it preloads several items on page, and I need to make it show pop-up when clicked on any of them.

I found this solution and tried it:

```
<div class="items">
    <div class="menu_item_btn" href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "itemquantity()">
        <%= item.name %>
    </div>

    <div id="light" class="itemshowcontent">
        <p>Some content</p>
        <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "closeitemquantity()">Close</a>
    </div>

    <div id="fade" class="blackoverlay"></div>
</div>
```

where js:

```
<script>
    function itemquantity() {
        document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'
    }
    function closeitemquantity() {
        document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'
    }
</script>
```

It works, however when I select quantity, it always selects it only for the first item that comes.

If click on second item (or any other), the pop-up is still for the first one.

I believe this is because I use getElementById, as ID is used for only one object.

I tried changing to getElementsByClassName, but then it doesn't work at all. So, my question is how to make it work?

Should I stick to using classes? Or somehow use ID, within classes?

I apologise if it's simple question, I'm not really familiar with JS.

Any advice appreciated.

EDIT: 
Here are some images for what I'm doing. This is page with listed objects:
[image: Objects preloaded]
These are the objects preloaded from DB shown in a list. When you click on any of them, this pop-up comes up:
[image]
to select quantity. 
I'm developing in elixir and phoenix framework.

Comment: When you have this on the page more than once, do you have **all** of it more than once? E.g., multiple `.items` elements as well?

Comment: Hey @T.J.Crowder, not sure If I understood you correctly, but yes, on the page I preload multiple objects from the db, and I need to show popup on click of the object. Within the popup there are options on what to do with selected object, which when selected reloads the page. So, basically each object has several functions available to be shown in popup.

Comment: Do you have multiple `.items` elements? The *entire* structure shown above is replicated?

Comment: Do your items all have the same ids `light` and `fade`?. If so change them to classes. Id's need to be unique.

Comment: @llya in what framework are you developing?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Oh, nope, the structure is used only once for the .items.

Comment: Hey @DavidDomain, yes that's what i was thinking, because ID are unique I need to uses classes, however I tried getElementsByClassName and it doesn't work. Maybe because there are many classes created (for each object), and it doesn't know which class to select. Also, I cannot create ID manually for each item, because it's dynamically preloading from database.

Comment: Hey @ShlomiHaver, I'm developing in Elixir/Phoenix framework!

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong but you said that every time you click the button the page reloads and the selected item is not changed, right?

Comment: @ShlomiHaver, you mean when I use ID's? Not really, I meant that within each pop-up (for each item) there are several options shown (also buttons). And if you click on any of the buttons within the pop-up, some code on server-side is executed, and the page reloads and shows all over again: different objects with pop-ups (onclick).

Comment: @Ilya Please show select list options and the js code you are using.

Comment: @ShlomiHaver I added pics for your reference of what it looks like. The options within each pop-up are just buttons (server-side executing), without js of it self.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117048/discussion-between-shlomi-haver-and-ilya).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `id` to each item and move `light` and `fade` out from `id` and to  class. Then, find `light` and `fade` by item `id` when click function is executed. See the following example.

```js
function getParent(itemChild) { // Get parent.
  var item = itemChild.parentElement;
  return item;
}
function itemquantity(itemChild) {
  var item = getParent(itemChild); // Get parent and it is the item.
  item.querySelector('.light').style.display='block'; // Find .light element as of item.
  item.querySelector('.fade').style.display='block'; // Find .fade element as of item.     
}
function closeitemquantity(itemChild) {
  var item = getParent(getParent(itemChild)); // You have to get parent twice and that is the item.
  item.querySelector('.light').style.display='none';  // Find .light element as of item.
  item.querySelector('.fade').style.display='none';   // Find .fade element as of item.      
}
```

```html
<div class="items" id="apple">
  <div class="menu_item_btn" href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "itemquantity(this)">
    Apple
  </div>

  <div class="light itemshowcontent">
    <p>Red Apple</p>
    <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "closeitemquantity(this)">Close</a>
  </div>

  <div class="fade blackoverlay"></div>
</div>

<div class="items" id="banana">
  <div class="menu_item_btn" href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "itemquantity(this)">
    Banana
  </div>

  <div class="light itemshowcontent">
    <p>Yello Banana</p>
    <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "closeitemquantity(this)">Close</a>
  </div>

  <div class="fade blackoverlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!! Thank you so much!